# Bootstrap grid, dropping fourth column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a four column grid where the max width is 960px. I made customized download and set up `@container-large-desktop` to `(950px + @grid-gutter-width)` and `@grid-gutter-width` to `10px`. This is what I want to do:
[image]

My issue is that it is dropping the fourth column. I've been trying to figure out but I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong? Also, I'm using **only the grid**. Manually I got rid of the rest.

This is my codepen: http://codepen.io/labanino/pen/ZQoWem

Thanks.

Comment: why not adjust the width of : `.col-md-3 { width: 23.8%;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to your CSS works:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The problem is that (for example) `.col-md-3` class is set to a width of 25%, so 4 * 25 = 100. But also have a 5px left and right padding, so (4 * 25%) + (4 * 10px) = something more than 100%.

Adding box sizing to all elements makes stuff like this a lot easier. It basically means that the padding is taken from the width.

### Note:

In the real world, you probably want to do it like this:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

see: https://css-tricks.com/international-box-sizing-awareness-day/

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the padding from the .col-md-3

```
#tv-player .col-md-3 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

and add it to the thumbnail:

```
.thumbnail {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download fresh new bootstrap CSS. It seemed to work for me.